# How to change default behavior to press Enter to send message in chat using Javascript UI kit Weavy

Tags: javascript, weavy

How to change default behavior to press Enter to send message in the Weavy chat using Javascript UI kit?

https://www.weavy.com/docs/reference/uikit-js

There is not reference at documentation about this

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

you can address this issue by creating a custom user interface, hosting Weavy on your own server, or employing a matching custom domain (requires upgrade) for iFrame script injection, although the last option is not optimal. We plan to incorporate this feature in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).